# How can I save google cloud build step text output to file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-build

I'm trying to use google cloud build. At one step, I need to get a list of all running compute instances.

```
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  args: ['compute', 'instances', 'list']
```

and it works fine. Problem starts when I tried to save the output to a file

---

**Trial 1**: failed

```
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  args: ['compute', 'instances', 'list', '> gce-list.txt']
```

---

**Trial 2**: failed

```
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  args: ['compute', 'instances', 'list', '>', 'gce-list.txt']
```

---

**Trial 3**: failed

```
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  args: >
      compute instances list > gce-list.txt
```

---

**Trial 4**: failed

```
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  args: |
      compute instances list > gce-list.txt
```

---

**UPDATE: 2018-09-04 17:50**

**Trial 5**: failed

1. Build an gcloud image based on ubuntu
2. Used that image to run custom script file 'list-gce.sh'
3. list-gce.sh calls `gcloud compute instances list`

For more details you can check this gist: 
https://gist.github.com/mahmoud-samy/e67f141e8b5d553de68a58a30a432ed2

Unfortunately I got this strange error:

rev 1

> ERROR: (gcloud) unrecognized arguments: list (did you mean 'list'?)

rev 2

> ERROR: (gcloud) unrecognized arguments: --version  (did you mean '--version'?)

Any suggestions, or references?

Comment: what works for me is `gcloud version | tee /dev/stderr > gcloud_version.txt`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In addition to other answers, to do `cmd > foo.txt`, you need to override the build entrypoint to bash (or sh):

```
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  entrypoint: /bin/bash
  args: ['-c', 'gcloud compute instances list > gce-list.txt']
```

Comment: what to do when the container is built from scratch and doesn't have even bash or sh installed? Example case https://github.com/anchore/syft/blob/main/Dockerfile

Answer (score 5):

Those commands are not executed in a shell, so shell operations such as pipes (`|`) and redirections (`>`) are not available.

---

## Workaround

Use a `gcloud` container which *does* have a shell. The `gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud` container should have `bash`, as it is ultimately [derived](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/blob/9bc5cffc909771827a5865d02e552c2b352b1b1b/gcloud/Dockerfile.slim) from an Ubuntu 16.04 image.

In your Cloud Build task sequence, execute a shell script which performs the `gcloud` calls for you and redirects the output to a file. This has some observations:

- You'll need to store the shell script somewhere sensible; probably in your source repository so it becomes available to the build.
- The `gcloud` container can still be used, as this will ensure the Google Cloud SDK tools are available to your script. You will need to override the `entrypoint` in the Cloud Build manifest to be `/bin/bash`, or some other shell, and pass the path to your script as an argument.
- As DazWilkin identifies [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52152526/how-can-i-save-google-cloud-build-step-text-output-to-file#comment91265679_52155786), the Cloud Build service account will also require the `compute.instances.list` permission to list instances.

The `/workspace` directory is mounted into all Cloud Build containers and its contents will be persisted between and accessible from subsequent build steps. If the output of the `gcloud` command, or a post-processed version, is require by subsequent build steps, you can write it out here.

Relevant [Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/create-custom-build-steps#example_executing_a_shell_script_from_your_source).

Comment: The Cloud Build service account will need `compute.instances.list` (`roles/compute.viewer`) and the build step will need to override `cloud-builders/gcloud` entrypoint with e.g. `/bin/bash` to get a shell.

Comment: @DazWilkin I wasn't intending the answer to be a full step-by-step description, but those are good points and I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: Apologies. Your answer is good and comprehensive. I suspect the IAM change would have been unclear to other readers.