# How can I call gcloud commands from a shell script during a build step?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I have automatic builds set up in Google Cloud, so that each time I push to the master branch of my repository, a new image is built and pushed to Google Container Registry.

These images pile up quickly, and I don't need all the old ones. So I would like to add a build step that runs a bash script which calls `gcloud container images list-tags`, loops the results, and deletes the old ones with `gcloud container images delete`.

I have the script written and it works locally. I am having trouble figuring out how to run it as a step in Cloud Builder.

It seems there are 2 options:

```
- name: 'ubuntu'
  args: ['bash', './container-registry-cleanup.sh']
```

In the above step in `cloudbuild.yml` I try to run the `bash` command in the `ubuntu` image. This doesn't work because the `gcloud` command does not exist in this image.

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: [what goes here???]
```

In the above step in `cloudbuild.yml` I try to use the `gcloud` image, but since "Arguments passed to this builder will be passed to `gcloud` directly", I don't know how to call my bash script here.

What can I do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can customize the entry point of your build step. If you need gcloud installed, use the gcloud cloud builder and do this

```
step:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    entrypoint: "bash"
    args:
      - "-c"
      - |
          echo "enter 1 bash command per line"
          ls -la
          gcloud version
          ...
```

Comment: Worked. Thank you!

Comment: I'm trying this with cloud-builders/docker and it fails saying source not found. I don't know if it's bash or sh but we need access to customize with variables from another step.

Answer (score -1):

As per the official documentation [Creating custom build steps](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/create-custom-build-steps) indicates, you need a custom build step to execute a shell script from your source, the step's container image must contain a tool capable of running the script.

The below example, shows how to configure your `args`, for the execution to perform correctly.

```
steps:
- name: 'ubuntu'
  args: ['bash', './myscript.bash']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/custom-script-test', '.']
images: ['gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/custom-script-test']
```

I would recommend you to take a look at the above documentation and the example as well, to test and confirm if it will help you achieve the execution of the script.

For your case, specifically, there is this other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52176379/12767257), where is indicated that you will need to override the endpoint of the build to `bash`, so the script runs. It's indicated as follow:

```
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  entrypoint: /bin/bash
  args: ['-c', 'gcloud compute instances list > gce-list.txt']
```

Besides that, these two below articles, include more information and examples on how to configure customized scripts to run in your Cloud Build, that I would recommend you to take a look.

- [CI/CD: Google Cloud Build — Custom Scripts](https://medium.com/serverlessguru/ci-cd-google-cloud-build-custom-scripts-12c9d23f9d4c)
- [Mastering Google Cloud Build Config Syntax](https://medium.com/@davidstanke/mastering-google-cloud-build-config-syntax-8c3024607daf)

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: I have read the documentation. This does not answer my question. I described a custom build step as option #1 in my original post. The question is how to make a `gcloud` request from a shell script without having to install and auth gcloud tools in an Ubuntu image, when Google already provides images with gcloud tools built in.

Comment: Hi @cilphex is this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52176379/12767257), what you are looking for? As clarified it on this answer, you will need to enforce the bash for it to run correctly. I will be looking for alternatives in the meantime.

Comment: That's great @cilphex ! Thanks for confirming it. Please, consider upvoting my answer, if you think in the end, I could help you.